# how to use .get() in a nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I use `.get()` to query for keys which may or may not be present in a dictionary.

```
In [1]: a = {'hello': True}
In [3]: print(a.get('world'))
None
```

I have, however, dictionaries where the key I want to check for is deeper in the structure and I do not know if the ancestors are present or not. If the dict is `b = {'x': {'y': {'z': True}}}` do I have to resort to

```
In [5]: b.get('x') and b['x'].get('y') and b['x']['y'].get('z')
Out[5]: True
```

to check for `'z'` when I do not know whether `'x'` and `'y'` exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can return an empty dictionary object from `dict.get()` to ease chaining calls:

```
b.get('x', {}).get('y', {}).get('z')
```

but perhaps you'd be better off catching the `KeyError` exception:

```
try:
    value = b['x']['y']['z']
except KeyError:
    value = None
```

Comment: As @Martijn points, in Python it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission. So, working with exceptions should be the right direction!